# Extjs change date picker days

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, frontend

[My date picker image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuAtw.png)

Hi, I have a problem with the days of my date picker in extjs. The date picker takes the first letter of the day. In my languague all days starts with D as you can see. Can I set a custom letters?

Thanks !! :D

Comment: Which language is it - Catalan or Gaelic?

Comment: The languague is Catalan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `getDayInitial` method with whatever is appropriate for your locale. It depends on the value of `Ext.Date.dayNames`.

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.Date.dayNames = ['D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'D4', 'D5', 'D6', 'D7'];

        Ext.define(null, {
            override: 'Ext.picker.Date',
            getDayInitial: function(value) {
                return 'X' + value[1];
            }
        });

        new Ext.picker.Date({
            renderTo: document.body
        });
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/233t)